# Possible bug: update_user_meta is updating two unique meta entries

Tags: user-meta, bug

On a CPT page I am checking to see if the user is logged in; if they are, I'm checking to see if they have a meta entry which is `'session-'` + the current page's stub. If they do, I increment the value by one.

I thought this was all working fine, but I've just noticed that it's actually incrementing two separate user_meta fields. At the moment I have three CPT pages (let's call them Burt, Ernie & Ralph); if I refresh the page for **Burt**, it increments my user_meta field (`session-burt`) by 1, which is great; however it *also* increments `session-ralph` by 1.

I don't have the **Ralph** page open, and I'm echoing out everything I can think of to try and trace down the erroneous line of code, but I can't see *why* it's doing it. It is incredibly annoying.

Here's my code. Hopefully I'm just blind to something really obvious and it's not a WP bug.

```
$stub = $post->post_name;

$sessionKey = 'session-' . $stub;
$viewedKey = $stub . '-lastviewed';

$sessionViewsArray = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, $sessionKey);
$sessionViews = (int)$sessionViewsArray[0];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sessionViewsArray);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h1>I think there are ' . $sessionViews . ' views</h1>';

$lastViewedArray = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, $viewedKey);
$lastViewedTime = $lastViewedArray[0];

if ($lastViewedTime) {
    $lastViewed = date('l jS F Y, g:ia', $lastViewedTime);
} else {
    $lastViewed = 'First time - good luck!';
}

$newSessionViews = $sessionViews + 1;

update_user_meta($current_user->ID, $sessionKey, $newSessionViews);
update_user_meta($current_user->ID, $viewedKey, time());

echo '<h1>I think I just updated ' . $sessionKey . '</h1>';

///
//  Now let's update the page views
///

$pageViewsArray = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'totalviews');
$pageViews = (int)$pageViewsArray[0];

$pageViews += 1;

update_post_meta($post->ID, 'totalviews', $pageViews);
```

It's worth noting that it only seems to be the one `session-ralph` entry that is affected; the `ralph-lastviewed` entry doesn't get updated if I refresh the Burt page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### UPDATE:

As per the *awesome* answer from @dalbaeb below, my solution was to use the following hook:

`remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);`

...which removed the `<link rel='next'...` and `<link rel='prev'...` tags from my header and immediately solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by chance using Firefox to test your page? If so its [prefetching function combined with WordPress `rel='next'`](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/wordpress-relnext-and-firefox-prefetching) could be the culprit. Check your page source for those `rel` tags, and see if Firebug registers an extra GET request to the page specified in the `href` attribute of the `rel` tag.

There is a Firefox extension [Fasterfox](http://fasterfox.mozdev.org/faq.html#What_is_prefetching), and it will prefetch *everything*. Disabling `adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head` will not help.
You should exit early in your code in those cases:

```
if ( isset ( $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MOZ"] ) and 'prefetch' === $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MOZ"] )
    return;
```

Comment: Check for `isset ( $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MOZ"] )`.

Comment: @dalbaeb That is *exactly* right - I was using Firefox, and using the hook `remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);` to remove the rel links solved the issue. I've updated my question with this.

Comment: @indextwo See my update to this answer. Your solution is not complete enough.

Comment: @toscho I appreciate that there may be a Firefox extension, however escaping the entire routine in these cases would actually make the displayed data seem more erroneous, as no figures would _ever_ be incremented. I've tested it and it works for me, and the client has tested it and it works for her.